# Entity donates to a charity in exchange for my work: do I need report this to the IRS when filing for my taxes?

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, donation

I'm doing some work in the US for some entity also located in the US, and I've been told:

> We will donate xxx USD on your behalf to one of several non-profits that you can choose.

I am a US tax resident. Do I have to report this to the IRS when filing for my taxes?

Comment: Are you also paid directly for your work (e.g. W-2, 1099)?

Comment: @yoozer8 no~~~~~

Comment: Why on earth would anyone agree to this?

Comment: @quid why not?~

Comment: Because you can just donate the money yourself after you get paid. In this arrangement you have no guarantee the money is actually donated.

Comment: @quid "you can just donate the money yourself after you get paid" does it have the same tax implications for me?

Comment: This is generally illegal, but if you are considering it as donating your time then there's nothing to report.

Comment: Can you give us more info on what you are trying to achieve with this setup? Is it "I don't need paying for this, but it would be nice if you gave some money to charity since you are getting work for free"? Or is it "I'd normally give 10% of my money to charity, so I'll get 10% of my clients to donate to charity instead of paying me and thus bypass some taxes"? (I'll assume it's not "give this money to a non-profit and I'll get the non-profit to sneakily redirect it to me", which is of course a theoretical possibility.)

Comment: I can think of reasons why someone might do this.  Sometimes I don't want to be paid for something, perhaps because that can cause people to flip their attitude from "this person is doing me a favour" to "this person is my employee".  Conversely some people can't seem to abide getting a benefit without somehow paying for it.  Getting them to make a donation to charity helps reconcile these two opposing drives.

Comment: @EricNolan then you’re doing a favor and the other person happens to donate some money somewhere and the two things aren't related.  If you’re doing work and being paid there’s no reason to forego receipt of the money.  Just donate the money yourself if that’s what you want to do with it.

Comment: @EricNolan the employer here is double dipping: they're evading payroll taxes on one hand, and deducting donations on the other. There's absolutely no benefit to the employee here, unless the employee is also interested in evading tax payments.

Answer (score 6):

This is going to depend on the answer to a seemingly simple question:

> **Will you, or anyone you are connected with, benefit from the donations made?**

In the "normal" circumstances, where the donation is going to a well-established registered charity and neither you, your family, your friends nor any business connected with them benefit from that charity's work, then you are pretty safe and you don't have to declare them as income. The donations are not a "payment" or "recompense" for your work, they are just a way of acknowledging your work.

As soon as there is any doubt about whether you, or anyone connected with you, benefits from the donations then you may be in trouble. For example, you may have a problem if the donations are:

- to the school your child attends;
- to a non-profit that employs your company to provide services;
- to a non-profit that someone in your family administers or works for
- to a non-profit that advances a political position you support

If there is the slightest doubt about whether you benefit I strongly recommend getting a lawyer to look at this. If you are doing this because you think it's a great way of getting paid while avoiding tax, then it's almost certainly illegal and the IRS has almost certainly seen it before.

You are also going to have to make sure you are not in the position of an employee. That would run you up against minimum wage laws and probably other stuff.

Comment: "That would run you up against minimum wage laws and probably other stuff" -- is an *employee* ever punished for working for less than minimum wage?

Comment: Note, $1 executive salaries happen [despite](https://www.quora.com/What-exemption-to-US-minimum-wages-law-permits-a-1-salary) being [illegal](https://slate.com/news-and-politics/2008/12/is-a-1-salary-paid-all-at-once-or-in-4-cent-installments.html). "The catch is that nobody is going to enforce the law here. If Jobs doesn't complain, nobody is going to complain for him."

Comment: @nanoman the article says that equity compensation doesn't count because "their values not yet fixed", but that's not true. The values are fixed at vest events and are in fact considered compensation. There are also a lot of exemptions for significant stakeholders (that may ran afoul of tax laws, however).

Answer (score 4):

It appears that your employer is violating some laws, and possibly you do too, with this arrangement.

It allows both of you to avoid the payroll/self-employment taxes, and allows you to be able to potentially effectively deduct the entirety of your income as a charity contribution.

Unless you're *volunteering* with a *registered non-profit*, minimum wage rules and payroll taxes apply. If you're categorized as a contractor, then you're expected to pay SE taxes on your earnings.

There's no way to *report this to the IRS* when filing your taxes, but if anyone reports you or your employer to the IRS tip line you may end up in a lot of trouble.

---

A nit-picking reader may claim that you can always report *something* to the IRS, but the problem is that there's no way to report such an arrangement in existing forms other than a plain statement, and in writing such a statement you'd be admitting to breaking some laws or helping others to break some laws, or both.

Comment: I hadn't thought of minimum wage. You have some good points here that I hadn't thought of.

Comment: I'd appreciate downvoters to explain what they're disagreeing with

Comment: "There's no way to *report this to the IRS* when filing your taxes" -- I thought you could always stay good with the IRS by filing truthfully and paying what you owe, even if the underlying income arrangement is somehow illegal. Even Al Capone could have stayed out of prison if he had dutifully filed. OP can simply declare income and pay SE to be safe, right? I don't think the IRS enforces minimum wage and in any case it would be the employer, not employee, who's punished. It doesn't make sense to me that OP will be in trouble with the IRS and there's no possible filing that can prevent it.

Comment: @nanoman well, potentially if the OP knows the amounts donated I guess he could declare it as 1099 income with all the taxes dutifully paid, or if the OP is characterized as an employee he can potentially file a substitute W2, but what I mean is that it wouldn't be a truthful report (see the jurat at the signature line), and in any case is likely to invite audit. As to whether or not the IRS enforces min. wage laws - it's irrelevant, if not the IRS then DOL, or some other acronym, someone will start looking.

Comment: @littleadv Okay, that's what I don't understand -- all the IRS can require is making a truthful report and paying the resulting tax owed. You say this proposed filing wouldn't be truthful -- why exactly, and what filing would be? Are you really saying that there is *no IRS form that allows OP to tell the truth* in this situation? Remember, even Al Capone had an option for telling the truth to the IRS (he just declined to do so). If OP doesn't declare income and the IRS later comes after OP for that, surely the IRS has to be able to say, "This is what you *should have filed*"?

Comment: @nanoman no, since arrangement is illegal there's no form for this situation. The IRS is able to say "This is what you *should have done*". Which is not to agree to such an arrangement, from the start. Similarly how they could tell Al Capone to not kill people or extort them from the start.

Comment: @littleadv There [totally is a form](https://www.nbcnews.com/business/taxes/dont-forget-declare-income-stolen-goods-illegal-activities-irs-says-rcna10345). Paying your taxes satisfies the IRS and doesn't trigger other punishment: "the IRS can’t share the information unless law enforcement has a case and gets a court order to get access to a taxpayer’s records". The IRS [says](https://www.irs.gov/publications/p525#en_US_2021_publink1000229557): "Income from illegal activities...must be included in your income on **Schedule 1 (Form 1040), line 8z, or on Schedule C**".

Comment: @nanoman feel free to write an answer then, and stop harassing me. What are you going to put exactly on line 8z or schedule C? You didn't get anything, you didn't donate anything. You'd be perjuring yourself. In the link you post here the situation is that the taxpayer *stole* something, I.e.: they did have income to declare and didn't declare it. Here the situation is that the taxpayer didn't have income, but should have. So the taxpayer has nothing to declare because he didn't receive any income, but he should have and the arrangement was to evade payroll taxes.

Comment: @littleadv If filing this way, OP's argument would be that the donation should be treated *as if* it were paid as wages to OP and then donated by OP. Lots of tax things are "as if". OP could include a letter explaining this, to show good faith. It seemed like the whole point you were making, that the scheme is wrong to the extent that "It allows both of you to avoid the payroll/self-employment taxes, and allows you to...deduct the entirety of your income as a charity contribution." If the IRS would take the position that it's a kind of "constructive" income subject to tax, then so can OP, no?

Comment: @nanoman: It wouldn't go on that line, since the activities aren't illegal.  Failure of the employer to list the income on a W-2 may be illegal but that's not what generates the income.  OP would just report it as "miscellaneous income for which he has no 1099" (there's a line for that, separate from the one for income from illegal activity) and then take the deduction (which leaves him responsible for SE tax)

Comment: @BenVoigt Line 8z is for miscellaneous "other income" that doesn't fit in any category on the form -- including but not limited to illegal income. In any case, given that littleadv somehow views the arrangement as illegal for OP to participate in at all, I was rebutting littleadv's argument that this meant OP could not properly file and pay taxes. I'm saying *even if it were* illegal income (which I don't believe), there's a place for it. It sounds like you mostly agree with [my answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/151226/64920).

Answer (score 3):

It is useful to separate the question of *your tax obligations* from any other concerns about the legitimacy of the arrangement. It seems the worst-case (for you) position that the IRS could take is that you *are being paid* as a contractor but have elected to have your customer *donate that payment on your behalf*.

This would be somewhat similar to elective payroll deductions for charitable donations that many employers offer -- you never see the money directly, but it is treated as paid to you and then donated by you to the third-party charity (normally this is only a small fraction of wages though).

So if you conservatively treat the transaction as (1) your receipt of contractor income and (2) your donation of that same amount, and you pay the consequences of that including full self-employment and income tax on (1) and limited deductibility of (2), then you should be in the clear. And if there is any doubt that the donation has actually happened and has benefited a legitimate third-party charity, you could *decline to claim* any deduction for (2) to be safe.

You may not like the cost of this approach (working induces negative cash flow), but it may be the best you can do with your "work for donation" setup, unless you can get reliable personal tax advice (which this answer is not) to justify being more aggressive, e.g., not considering the donated payment as income at all.

Apart from the above is any concern about whether, by directly donating your compensation instead of paying it to you, your customer is improperly employing you for less than minimum wage and/or failing to issue a required 1099 or W-2 and/or failing to pay its share of payroll taxes if you are deemed an employee. Any such investigation or enforcement would be directed against your customer/employer and not you, and could only *improve* your financial position relative to the above.

Comment: *"Any such investigation or enforcement would be directed against your customer/employer and not you"*  - welcome to the concept of "accessory to a crime".

Comment: @littleadv Hmm, so all the gig workers [fighting to be classified as employees](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/06/01/business/massachusetts-gig-workers-ballot.html) are in for a nasty surprise if they win -- since they willingly worked as contractors, they'll promptly be arrested for being accessories to their previous misclassification?! I don't think it works that way. Most labor laws are binding and punishable on employers but not on employees.

Comment: if they're fighting - then not willingly, right? In this case the OP *clearly* and *willingly* cooperated with the evasion scheme. This is not a labor law violation, it's a tax law violation.

Comment: @littleadv If OP pays full SE and income tax on the amount donated as I suggested, there doesn't seem to be any tax evasion. The IRS gets what they should. We've established that you think it would be perjury but I don't see it. Re gig workers -- look at those who happily worked for a time *before* starting to fight, or those who are *still* fine with being contractors and aren't fighting. The point stands, none of the workers will remotely be charged as accessories even if it is determined they willingly worked while illegally classified as contractors.

Comment: I understand your point, I disagree. The OP in this situation *clearly* co-operated with the *employer's* scheme to evade taxes. Even if the OP clears his conscience and pays *his* share, the *employer* is still the one evading taxes, and still with the OP's co-operation. This is not the case with the gig economy workers.

Comment: @littleadv Great, we're making progress. What tax exactly is employer evading? Are you talking about payroll tax? You refer to OP's "share", but I proposed that OP pay *full* self-employment tax (15.3%), which is equal to employer *plus* employee payroll tax (in an employment arrangement, it's split 7.65%+7.65%). A client that pays a genuine contractor doesn't owe *any* payroll tax because the contractor covers it all.

Comment: Employer is evading income tax, for starters.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136880/discussion-between-nanoman-and-littleadv).